# Two-factor authentication problems

Tags: iphone, two-factor-authentication

I want to log in via a laptop on my iCloud that I have 2FA on, but my iPhone is currently unavailable. So I can't log in because I can't reach the 6-digit code. What can I do?

Comment: I am often assumed that when I have a virtual guest macOS installed on my physical host Mac, the two will use each other to do two factor authentication.

Comment: You could try adding a local phone number as a trusted number. Apple can call that number and speak the 6 digit number.

Comment: Mine come through as iMessages to the Mac, too. I 'can be reached for messages' at my me.com & my phone number. 'Messages in cloud' is also on.